# Connecting to ACR122 on centos

Tags: centos, nfc, lib-nfc, acr122

I have an ACR122 and I am trying to connect to it using lib-nfc. (is this the correct step?)
I don't have much knowledge regarding NFC (any links for beginners in C for linux are appreciated)

I have lib-nfc on my machine (centos 6.5 64bit) and if I do nfc-list I get:

NFC device: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened

So I assume it is connected (I don't see any red light on)
When I try to run the ./nfc-pool example I get this:

```
/home/user/acr122/libnfc/examples/.libs/lt-nfc-poll uses libnfc libnfc-1.7.1-11-gbb9babb
NFC reader: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
NFC device will poll during 30000 ms (20 pollings of 300 ms for 5 modulations)
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb        Invalid RDR_to_PC_DataBlock frame
nfc_initiator_poll_target: Input / Output Error
```

What am I doing wrong? Any links to tutorials or books regarding NFC/USB communication are welcomed with examples in C if possible. I am really trying to learn and not have someone write anything for me.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a PC/SC daemon running on that machine? If yes, you might want to try if disabling it helps. Or you might at least want to prevent it from accessing the ACR122U.

Comment: I started the daemon and then I got a red light on the ACR.

Comment: If the daemon was not running before, than that's not the cause of your problem. Though you could try to change the backend used by libnfc from arc122_usb to acr122_pcsc.

Comment: How can I change from acr122_usb to acr122_pcsc?